# Is it possible to pass a variable to (Beautifulsoup) soup.find()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I need to pass a variable to the soup.find() function, but it doesn't work :( 
Does anyone know a solution for this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div> blabla
<p class='findme'> p-tag content</p>
</div>'''

sources = {'source1': '\'p\', class_=\'findme\'',
           'source2': '\'span\', class_=\'findme2\'',
           'source1': '\'div\', class_=\'findme3\'',}

test = BeautifulSoup(html)

# this works
#print(test.find('p', class_='findme'))
# >>> <p class="findme"> p-tag content</p>


# this doesn't work
tag = '\'p\' class_=\'findme\''

# a source gets passed
print(test.find(sources[source]))
# >>> None
```

I am trying to split it up as suggested like this:

```
pattern = '"p", {"class": "findme"}'
tag = pattern.split(', ')
tag1 = tag[0]
filter = tag[1]
date = test.find(tag1, filter)
```

I don't get errors, just None for date. The problem is propably the content of tag1 and filter The debuger of pycharm gives me:

```
tag1 = '"p"'
filter = '{"class": "findme"}'
```

Printing them doesn't show these apostrophs. Is it possible to remove these apostrophs?

Comment: No, that variable would not work, because that's not a tag name..

Answer (score 3):

The first argument is a tag *name*, and your string doesn't contain that. BeautifulSoup (or Python, generally) won't parse out a string like that, it cannot guess that you put some arbitrary Python syntax in that value.

Separate out the components:

```
tag = 'p'
filter = {'class_': 'findme'}
test.find(tag, **filter)
```

Comment: Thank you for your coomment. The problem is that I am reading the variable form a dicitonary (see my first post) so this wouldn't work

Comment: @user3199535: and you cannot build that dictionary differently?

Comment: @user3199535: You'd have to parse that string yourself, pull out the class name and the tag, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so far. I am running in some problems trying it (in my first posting)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it, thanks again.

```
dic_date = {'source1': 'p, class:findme', other sources ...}

pattern = dic_date[source]
tag = pattern.split(', ')
if len(tag) is 2:
    att = tag[1].split(':')  # getting the attribute
    att = {att[0]: att[1]}  # building a dictionary for the attributes
    date = soup.find(tag[0], att)
else:
    date = soup.find(tag[0])  # if there is only a tag without an attribute
```

Well it doesn't look very nice but it's working :)

Comment: Why string it? `dic_date = {'source1': {'tag': 'p', {'filter': {'class': 'findme'}}}}` then use Martijn's approach... `pattern = dic_date['source1']` and `date = soup.find(pattern['tag'], **pattern.get('filter', {})` etc...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay. I am sorry but I don't get what you are doing. Could you give me a hint? Specially what these ** are for. I couldn't find anything. A link or something I can search for would also do it.