# BeautifulSoup: How to pass a variable into soup.find({variable])

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to search an XML file provided by the SEC (this is public data). Beautiful Soup works very well for referencing tags but I can not seem to pass a variable to its find function. Static content is fine.  I think there is a gap in my python understanding that I can't seem to figure out. (I code a few days a year, not my main role)

File:
https://reports.adviserinfo.sec.gov/reports/CompilationReports/IA_FIRM_SEC_Feed_02_08_2023.xml.gz

I download, unzip and then create the soup from the file using lxml.

```
with open(Firm_Download_name,'r') as f:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
```

Next is where I am running into trouble, I have a list of Firm CRD numbers (these are public numbers identifying the firm) that I am looking for in the XML file and then pulling out various data points from the child tags.

If I write it statically such as:

```
soup.find(firmcrdnb="5639055").parent
```

This works perfectly, but I want to loop through a list of CRD numbers and pull out a different block each time.  I can not figure out how to pass a variable to the soup.find function.

I feel like this should be simple. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Here is my current attempt:

```
searchstring = 'firmcrdnb="'+Firm_CRD+'"'
select_firm = soup.find(searchstring).parent
```

I have tried other similar setups and reviewed other stack exchanges such as [Is it possible to pass a variable to (Beautifulsoup) soup.find()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352168/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-variable-to-beautifulsoup-soup-find) but just not quite getting it.

Here is an example of the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<IAPDFirmSECReport GenOn="2017-09-30">
<Firms>
<Firm>
<Info SECRgnCD="MIRO" FirmCrdNb="9999" SECNb="999-99999" BusNm="XXXX INC." LegalNm="XXX INC" UmbrRgstn="N"/>
<MainAddr Strt1="9999 XXXX" Strt2="XXXX" City="XXX" State="FL" Cntry="XXX" PostlCd="999999" PhNb="999-999-9999" FaxNb="999-999-9999"/>
<MailingAddr Strt1="9999 XXXX" Strt2="XXXX" City="XXX" State="FL" Cntry="XXX" PostlCd="999999" />
<Rgstn FirmType="Registered" St="APPROVED" Dt="9999-01-01"/>
<NoticeFiled>
```

Thanks

ps: if anyone has ideas on how to improve the speed of the search on this large file I'd appreciate that to. I get messages such as "pydevd warning: Computing repr of soup (BeautifulSoup) was slow (took 43.83s)"  I did install and import chardet per the beautifulsoup documentation but that hasn't seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where I got turned around but my static answer did in fact not work.

The tag is "info" and the attribute is "firmcrdnb".

The answer that works was:

```
select_firm = soup.find("info", {"firmcrdnb" : Firm_CRD}).parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use,

```
select_firm = soup.find(attrs={'firmcrdnb': str(Firm_CRD)}).parent
```

Comment: I appreciate the help unfortunately it did not work.  It is still returning the same error 
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something.  If it works statically, have you tried something such as:

```
list_of_crds = ["11111","22222","33333"]

for crd in list_of_crds:
    result = soup.find(firmcrdnb=crd).parent
    ...
```

Comment: same error. I wrote as:

list_of_crds = ["5639055"]
for crd in list_of_crds:
    result = soup.find(firmcrdnb=crd).parent

It has something to do with how beautifulsoup is taking the value passed to it. I find it odd that I pass it firmcrdnb="5639055" where no quotes or anything is being used for the attribtue "firmcrdnb".   Essentially it isn't interpreting the variable being passed and adding {} doesn't change this.